# Sum content values for each parent node

Tags: xml, xslt

For each value of the node parent, I want to sum the related element values. In the below example, I am expecting to have 3 results : 30 for the first parent, 50 for the second and 0 for the 3rd parent as it has no parent value.
can you help me getting this result please and rectify my code ?  :

Example file :

```
<root>
<parent>
<parentValue>Val1</parentValue>
<element>
<elementname>A</elementname>
<elementvalue>10</elementvalue>
</element>
<element>
<elementname>A</elementname>
<elementvalue>20</elementvalue>
</element>
</parent>
<parent>
<parentValue>Val2</parentValue>
<element>
<elementname>B</elementname>
<elementvalue>50</elementvalue>
</element>
</parent>
<parent>
<element>
<elementname>C</elementname>
<elementvalue>60</elementvalue>
</element>
</parent>
</root>
```

Code :

```
<xsl:template match="/">
    <xsl:for-each select="/root/parent/parentValue">
      <xsl:variable name="result">
        <xsl:value-of select="sum(elementvalue)" />
      </xsl:variable>
    </xsl:for-each>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Set up two templates

```
  <xsl:template match="parent[parentValue]">
     <xsl:value-of select="sum(element/elementvalue)"/>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="parent[not(parentValue)]">0</xsl:template>
```

https://xsltfiddle.liberty-development.net/b4GWVn

Or a single one

```
  <xsl:template match="parent">
     <xsl:value-of select="sum(.[parentValue]/element/elementvalue)"/>
  </xsl:template>
```

https://xsltfiddle.liberty-development.net/b4GWVn/1

Comment: Thank you that works!, but what if the parentvalue node is not at the same level as element value node, for example : <parent><sub-parent><parentValue>10</parent></sub-parent></parentValue ? Hw can I resolve it, do i need to do call template ?

Comment: You can simply change the path in the predicates to `sub-parent/parentValue` e.g. `match="parent[sub-parent/parentValue]"`.

Comment: No it is displaying the whole xml file as a result :(

Comment: You will to edit your question and provide minimal but complete samples demonstrating the issue or even ask a new question. When I edit the previous sample to put the `parentValue` elements into a `sub-parent` container the code continues to work once the predicates have been adapted: https://xsltfiddle.liberty-development.net/b4GWVn/2

Comment: thanks for your reply. Please find here the link for the new question : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49479982/sum-element-values-per-parents-values